Vim words syntax highlighting
How can I in Vim highlight, e.g., the first 10 words  in a line ?
I have found in Stackoverflow the answer for the first word :
/^\s*\w\+/

but I cannot figure how to tinker it for 10 words, or any number of words, by the way.

You are not supposed to find these things on stack overflow. You are supposed to learn how to use your tools properly (:help user-manual) and refer to the relevant section of the documentation when you need to dig deeper (:help \+ and scroll around).

I acknowlede your comment, but the answer given by @Kent shows that even if I had rtfm, I could not have come out with such a sophisticated answer (for me, at least). I simply hope that this answer will be as useful for other users, as it has been for me. Again, sorry

There is nothing sophisticated in that answer.

I see thqt you hqve deleted your downvote. This is elegant. Thank you.

Does this help?
/\v^\s*(<\w+>\s*){,5}

In the screenshot, it "highlights" 0-5 words as an example.


it helps, definitely ! I just noted that if I try with {,10} it works except for line 1 and stops before e.g. because I suppose this is not considered as a "word" but as a "Word". But this is not important at all. You made my day...
